# Change Apache Port on Plesk

Tags: port

I have googled my eyes for the past three hours yet failed to find an answer as to HOW do I change the default Apacht PORT on Plesk.

I want to put all Hosts to Port 81. Updating the central config file is trivial, the funny thing is, however, that the per-host configuration files generated by plesk all have port 80 listed as default, for example:

```
<VirtualHost 217.172.183.206:80>
        ServerName   foobar.com:80
```

I'd like plesk to write whatever port I like there instead of port 80.

Is there a way?

Comment: Administration panels are off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put a help request out for you to my tech support team.  I'll have a response for you soon.  Thanks for your patience.

-------EDIT--------

Ok, here's what he told me.

"If you change the port in vhost's httpd.include, it will be overwritten by websrvmng when you add a new domain. As a possible solution you can use Event manager and event trigger for creating new domains with executing script for changing port number for vhosts. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
MY_FILEPATH="/var/www/vhosts"
MY_FILE="httpd.include"
MY_REPLACE=":81"
find $MY_FILEPATH  -name $MY_FILE -exec perl -p -i -e "s[:80][$MY_REPLACE]g" {} \;
service httpd restart"
```

Let me know if that helps.

Drew from Parallels
@ParallelsPanel

Comment: Did this work? Doesn't the event work like this:  CP Add Hosting Domain -> Execute Custom Event -> Plesk write config file?  In which case any changes would be overwritten?  It would seem to work like this for modifications.